# SQL Server: Cross Database Query; Ownership chaining; Stored Procedure Signature/Certificate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, security

I'm trying to allow an impersonated stored procedure to access a view in a different database, using permissions set up for a certificate that the SP has been signed with.

#### Setup (simplified)

DatabaseA

- Table1
- ViewForeign: SELECT * FROM DatabaseB.ExposedView
- ViewResult: SELECT * FROM Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN ViewForeign VF ON t1.SomeKey = VF.SomeKey
- Stored Procedure GetData -> SELECT * FROM ViewResult

DatabaseB:

- Tables...
- View ExposedView -> Select * FROM SomeTables...

My DatabaseA has some privileged users, which are allowed to do lots of things, let's call one of them "SuperUser". For them, a user also exists in DatabaseB, so there's no problem with them accessing the exposed views in DatabaseB.
Now I've created a very limited user, let's call it "StupidUser", who's only got Execute permission on the DatabaseA.GetData SP. To avoid also granting SELECT or other permissions, I've create the SP `WITH EXECUTE AS 'SuperUser'`
This is all fine until a query accesses the other database:
`The server principal "SuperUser" is not able to access the database "DatabaseB" under the current security context.`
A bit of study of what's become my bible, [Erland Sommarskog's blog](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html)    reveals Ownership Chaining to be the culprit.
So I've tried to sign my SP with a certificate in DatabaseA:

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE AccessResourcesReadOnly 
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'veryComplicatedPassword'
    WITH SUBJECT = 'AccessResourcesReadOnly', EXPIRY_DATE = '2029-01-31T00:00:00'
ADD SIGNATURE TO [dbo].[GetData]  BY  CERTIFICATE  AccessResourcesReadOnly WITH PASSWORD = 'veryComplicatedPassword'
```

#### stuck here:

Now I'm trying to add a user for that certificate with Connect/Select permissions in DatabaseB for the exposed views. Running

```
CREATE USER AccessResourcesFromCertificateReadOnly  
FROM CERTIFICATE AccessResourcesReadOnly;
```

in ´DatabaseB´ results in

```
Cannot find the certificate 'AccessResourcesReadOnly', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Creating the certificate in ´master´ instead didn't help; I've tried that and then that certificate name can neither be found for `ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.GetData` in DatabaseA nor for `CREATE USER FROM CERTIFICATE` in DatabaseB.
What am I doing wrong? How can I sign `DatabaseA.GetData` in a way that the SP is allowed to access `DatabaseB.ExposedView`?

Answer (score 1):

You should `export certificate` and `import` it into `DatabaseB`, your certificate should exist in both databases, for now you have it only in `DatabaseA`, that's why you get

> Cannot find the certificate 'AccessResourcesReadOnly', because it does
>   not exist

The complete solution from the cited blog is:

1. Create a certificate in the target database, that is, PlaySign in
   this example.
2. Create a user from the certificate.
3. Grant the user the permissions needed.
4. Export the certificate.
5. Import the certificate into the originating database.
6. Sign the procedure in question.
7. Optional: drop the private key.

P.S. In your case simple `cross database chaining` will also work.

Comment: [This is the link to an example script](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#crossdbcert) in topic in Erland's article.

Comment: Thanks, looks as though I've missed a step then; I'll test and report back/accept.

Comment: Hmm, I still get `The server principal "SuperUser" is not able to access the database "DatabaseB" under the current security context` after exporting the certificate, importing it into the source DB and signing the SP. The user in the target database has (for now) been added to db_datareader, and I've also tried to grant it select explicitly. Still no luck. Cross database chaining is not a real option, my "simple case" is heavily simplified from the actual database.

Comment: It looks as though I may have had it the wrong way round (http://rusanu.com/2006/03/07/call-a-procedure-in-another-database-from-an-activated-procedure/):
It works when creating the certificate in DatabaseA, signing the SP there, then exporting the certificate without the private key to the targeted DB, creating a user there and Granting it Authenticate and whatever other permissions.